# Javaee asynchronous request : Dispatching even after response closed

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-ee-6

I'm reading the OSCWCD books by Charles Lyon on section about asynchoronous request. It says that in a asynchronous cycle, one can dispatch even when a response has been committed. I don't understand why so? Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The general approach for asynchronous approach is that client will open a new channel to receive the asynchronous response and will provide the handle of that channel to the server. The asynchronous response is not sent on the intial client request/response channel, rather it is sent on a different channel, which remains active till the client does not receive the asynchronous response.

If client is not able to provide any channel for the server to send the asynchronous response, then another approach is to use the polling. In this case, server as part of the intial request response, will provide a polling URL. The client can poll it periodicall, and when server has the response ready, will return the response. When server does not have a response, it should return a meaningful in-progress message.

Comment: Still your answer does not answer my main question. Why we can dispatch eventhough a response has been committed?

Comment: @yapkm01 we can dispatch eventhough a response has been committed? Generlly once you commit the response, then you cannot send any further info on the same response object or associated channel. As I mentioned, client should listen for aysnchronous response on a different channel/socket and server can comit the async response on that.